# Trying to build a data extension where I limit recipients to those who've selected only one value from a picklist

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I am trying to build a data extension for contacts who have selected one option on a picklist on a form. The picklist has roughly 70 different options to select from, and I'm only looking to collect those contacts who selected one option - meaning it can be any of the 70 options, as long as they did not select multiple.

Right now my DE is surfacing all those who have entered any response. Do I need to go in and make it reflect "Picklist value is equal to A" **OR** "Picklist value is equal to B" **OR** "Picklist value is equal to C" etc., or is there a command I am missing that can select the field I'm looking to populate and then having it only surface those contacts who have selected just one value?

Appreciate the insight - Data Extensions are a whole new world to me and while I've worked through some Trailhead/accelerators I'm still getting the hang of it. Thanks!

Comment: How are you populating the DE? SQL, Ampscript, API?

Comment: Built a filtered DE off a base extension with all subscribers that meet the minimum requirement for that subscriber pool.

Comment: Ok, could you share an example of a value that shows that a customer selected multiple options from the picklist?